# How can I save the value of multiple input boxes to local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a web app in which everytime the user presses 'enter' a new input box is added to the page. I want the values of each input box to be saved when the user clicks the save button. So when the user clicks the save button, all text saves after they refresh. So far, all the positions of the input boxes are saved correctly. All input boxes are appended children to the 'main' element.

```
let main = document.getElementById('main');
let ls=window.localStorage;
function saveToLS(e) {
    ls.setItem("content", main.innerHTML);
    for(let i = 0; i < main.children; i++){
        ls.setItem(`inputBox${i}`, main.children[i].value);
    }
}

function loadElements(e) {
    if(ls) {
        main.innerHTML = ls.getItem("content");
        for(let i = 0; i < main.children.length; i++) {
              main.children[i].addEventListener("keydown", inputKeyClick);
              main.children[i].value = ls.getItem(`inputBox${i}`);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I've appended some more info

Comment: What is `ls` ? it doesn't seem to be declared.

Comment: Local storage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for every `enter` key pressed you should fetch the local storage, parse the JSON and store again.

assuming this is your `inputKeyClick`:

```js
function inputKeyClick(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        [...main.children].forEach((item, index) => {
          localStorage.setItem(`inputBox${index}`, item.value)
      })
   }
}
```

This is just an idea that can be improved according to your needs

Comment: Only thing I will say is that main.children is an HTML collection, not an array, so you must add the line of code: let children = Array.prototype.slice.call(main.children); Only then can you do a foreach loop on children